# How to test existence of parent object before testing value or child

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs

What would be the best way to test for the existence of a deeply nested property using Jest. Trying to target the particular object I want will get me an undefined error because its parent object doesn't exist:

```
test('returns data from `server/index.js`', () => {
  const data = axios.get(httpObj)
     .then(data, => {
        expect(data.els[4]).not.toBeNull() 
        // ^ TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
  })
})
```

Should I chain these in some way so I can first test for the existence of the object, then test for the existence of the inner object? The equivalent of doing something like this in an if-statement

```
if (obj && obj[4] && obj[4].hasOwnProperty('myProp')) {
  // pass
}
```

Or when doing multiple tests on one element like this, should there be separate tests?

```
test('returns data from `server/index.js`', () => {
  const data = axios.get(httpObj)
     .then(data, => {
        expect(data).not.toBeNull() 
  })
})

test('data returned from `server/index.js` api contains my property', () => {
  const data = axios.get(httpObj)
     .then(data, => {
        expect(data.els[4]).not.toBeNull() 
  })
})
```

I have also tried:

```
const expected = {/* very large object */}
test('returns data from `server/index.js` and it contains an array containing the `expected` object', () => {
  expect(data.els[4]).toEqual(
    expect.objectContaining(expected)
  )
})
```

This works a bit? better, but requires me to have this very large object declared within the test file. This very deep comparison combined with just a static blob of data in my test file feels brittle to me. Is there a more canonical way than what I've tried

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this. The most vanilla way would be to just explicitly check like `obj && obj.childObj && obj.childObject.anotherChild` like you are doing in your first example. You could also use a library like lodash and use `_.get(obj, 'childObj.anotherChild')`. There is also a proposal right now to add some syntax to javascript that would make this easier by doing `obj?.childObj?.anotherChild` if you are using babel, babel 7 will support transpiling that syntax.

As far as actually testing your data goes I think you can safely make assumptions about how your data should look in the tests. The danger you run into by testing each attribute individually is that if your data changes shape for whatever reason you have way more tests you have to fix, as opposed to just assuming in one test what your data will look like.

Comment: is that pretty standard to include third party libraries like lodash in a testing file? Seems like you'd maybe just want to use the testing framework, but yeah definitely an option. I'm not seeing the `obj?.childObj?.anotherChild` syntax compile with babel even with the stage-0 option. In any case, I think your point about data is good. That should be pretty stable, so I think I will go for my third option. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Babel 7 will support the `?.`. Babel 7 hasn't been released yet but is in beta right now I believe. As far as using libraries in a test file I think is pretty standard. In fact, there are many libraries that are designed to help stream line testing, like react-test-utils if you are using react, or nock, which is used to help mock requests.